# Alternative methods to using SetCurrentDirectory in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, path, directory

I have a code to repair in VBA, which is a language that I'm learning as I go. The code calls an external exe file from a networked drive. The exe was updated recently from V5.0 to V5.3 and since that update the directories have become an issue. This is how the executable is called from the VBA code:

```
Sub RunExecutable()
Dim wsh As Object
SetCurrentDirectory "\\<path>\" 
Statusnum = wsh.Run(Command:="program.exe ""\\<path>\inputfile.gdp""", WindowStyle:=1, waitonreturn:=True)
```

This used to work perfectly. But since program.exe was updated, the path for some of it's working files has become duplicated when running from the above script. I suspect that the SetCurrentDirectory line is causing the problem. The working directory for program.exe should be, for example:

```
\\Drive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\
```

But program.exe now wants to write its working files to this duplicated path:

```
\\Drive\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\DRIVE\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FOLDER3\
```

Which doesn't exist on our network, and program.exe then crashes. If I create those subfolders for it to work in, it operates perfectly.

What I want to know is, is there an alternative way to call the .exe file without setting the current directory in VBA? Because the path I set as the current directory is what is being duplicated when program.exe is trying to run, and I have no way to modify the .exe file. The .exe works fine when not being called by this VBA code, there are no issues with the directories.

I tried putting in the exact path to the .exe file in this line:

```
wsh.Run(Command:="<path>/program.exe .....
```

and removing the SetCurrentDirectory command, but in response I get an error saying that the .exe file cannot be located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing the following:

```
Sub RunExecutable()
Dim wsh As Object
SetCurrentDirectory "\\<path>\" 
Statusnum = wsh.Run(Command:="program.exe ""\\<path>\inputfile.gdp""", WindowStyle:=1, waitonreturn:=True)
```

To this (you might have to also get rid of the \ before inputfile.gdp, depends on the end of your path and whether it ends with a \ or not):

```
Sub RunExecutable()
Dim wsh As Object
SetCurrentDirectory "\\<path>\" 
Statusnum = wsh.Run(Command:="program.exe ""inputfile.gdp""", WindowStyle:=1, waitonreturn:=True)
```

Or a slightly different approach using Shell Commands:

```
Sub RunExecutable()
Dim SetCurrentDirectory As String, varProc As Variant
On Error Resume Next
SetCurrentDirectory = "C:\Your\Path\program.exe" 'Your path here
varProc = Shell(SetCurrentDirectory , 1)
```

Comment: That seems like it should work, but returns Run-time error '91' - Object variable or with block variable not set. When I view the line causing the problem it only tells me Statusnum = empty.

I suspect you are right that this is where the duplication is coming from though, as the files that are being written to the duplicated directory by the .exe are prefixed with the name of the input file in that line of code.

My path does end with a \ , so this isn't required before inputfile.gdp

Comment: @AdamFeneley I've updated my answer to include a slightly different approach by using the Shell commands, you could give that a try, also please could you mark my response as an answer if it has helped you, thanks.

Comment: Thanks :) Your answer has helped me move forward towards a solution. The code is now launching the program, seemingly without the duplicated directory, but the exe file is no longer executing automatically, despite the input data file apparently being imported with the run command. I'll keep digging.

Instead of executing the required calculations from my input file automatically, as it did previously, the window now opens up as though I have just launched the software package to create a new project (it used to just run hidden in the background without need for my input).